# Adding result of loop to data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Hi I am new to learning R.

I am running a loop to find out number of man based on their region and value "v" in data frame specified bellow. I would like to save the result of the loop to data frame so that I can work with it. Thank you for your help.

```
data<-data.frame(x=rep(c("man", "woman"),500),reg=rep(1:5, 200), v=c(seq(100,1,length.out = 500),c(seq(1,100,length.out = 500))))

for (i in seq(0, 100, 10)) {

  print(paste("interval <", i, "-", i+10,">"))
  data %>% 
    filter(data$x == "man" & data$v >= i & data$v <= i +10) %>%   
    group_by(Region = reg) %>% 
    summarize(No_man = n()) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    print()
  if (i+10 > 90) {break}
}
```

Comment: Have those results stored into another object like so `tempdat <- data %>% ...`. I think this would be the easiest way out of your predicament.

Comment: Hi, I added the object tempdat in to the loop like you mentioned, but all that is written out to the tempdat object is the last interval (90-100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `for` loop here -- we can use `cut` to create the intervals inside a `mutate` call:

```
library(dplyr)

res <- 
data %>% 
  filter(v <= 100 & x == "man") %>% 
  mutate(Interval = cut(v, seq(0, 100, 10))) %>% 
  group_by(Region = reg, Interval) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  ungroup()

head(res)
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Region Interval     n
#   <int> <fct>    <int>
#1      1 (0,10]       9
#2      1 (10,20]     10
#3      1 (20,30]     10
#4      1 (30,40]     10
#5      1 (40,50]     10
#6      1 (50,60]     10
```

Believe this is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was mighty usefull :), this is much more elegant solution...and it actually works :D compared to mine anyways.

Comment: If it helped, feel free to upvote and accept as an answer

Comment: Sorry it took some time...answer accepted, as for the upvote...I have less than 15 rep. so it will probably take a while before it shows up for everyone.